# quote value manually before passing to database

Tags: ruby, escaping, sinatra, sequel, quoting

Everything's clear when `WHERE` clauses are concerned:

```
puts $DB[:users].where('field = ?', "'").sql   # SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (field = '\'')
puts $DB[:users].where(field: "'").sql   # SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`field` = '\'')
```

But what about `ORDER BY` ones?

```
puts $DB[:users].order_by(
    ("field = '%s'" % "'").lit
).sql   # SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY field = '''
```

Comment: I can't help you but I'm curious, I've never seen an `ORDER BY` with a value like that, what does it mean exactly?

Comment: Consider a page with a list of users. I want them to be displayed as follows: first users from my town go, then from my country, then anybody else. One way to do this is: `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY town == '<my town>' DESC, country == '<my country>' DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you [`quote`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/quote) to sanitize your string:

```
puts $DB[:users].order_by(
    ("field = %s" % ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote("'")).lit
).sql    # SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY field = ''''
```

For `sequel` you should use [`literal_append`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-literal_append):

```
puts $DB[:users].order_by(
    ($DB[:users].literal_append("field = ", "'")).lit
).sql    # SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY field = ''''
```

Comment: Yep, I'm looking for something like this, but I don't use `rails`, I'm using `sinatra`.

Comment: That's not `rails` - it's `active-record`... I'll see if I can find the counterpart in `sequel`

Comment: There's also [literal](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Database.html#method-i-literal) method.